# PHP session not working page by page

Tags: php

I have two different page with below code. I trim whole code because more than 1000 lines and therefore trim what I did.

In the first page I remove session and fill with new array.

firstpage.php

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['new'] = 'test';
print_r($_SESSION); // Session Working fine here at the bottom of page.
```

secondpage.php

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

But in second page show empty array()! I don't have any idea why such this happen

First page header:

```
PHPSESSID   e73jddq9fqhaeeav346h724js7  xxx.ttt.com 35B /  Session
```

Second page header:

```
PHPSESSID   e73jddq9fqhaeeav346h724js7  xxx.ttt.com 35B /  Session
```

both is same.

The script works fine on windows PHP but in cpanel(linux base) doesn't work!

Comment: Because you create a completely new and therefore independent session.

Comment: two page is completely different and independent! Do I need to remove the second page?

Comment: @arkascha and PranayAher:  I don't think you know how PHP sessions work.

Comment: Try to Unset the session above the `session_start();`

Comment: @Sven Then why don't you post an idea almighty session master instead of criticising ideas

Comment: Your code looks completely ok. My best guess: Did you accept the session cookie? If there is no way transporting the session id generated by the first `session_start()` over to the second page, then the session data cannot be found.

Comment: @Sven Yes, As far as I learn, I need to add in every page And it works fine on windows but after uploading on cpanel the problem happens.

Comment: Now THAT is interesting information! Please edit your question and add this to it. Also do some more debugging: Use Firebug in Firefox (or the analogue tool in Chrome) to record and see the HTTP headers that are being sent on the first and second page.

Comment: Can you check if your session path `session_save_path()` in file system has correct permissions? The session file is updated at the very end of the process when session is closed. Just by printing `$_SESSION` var right after setting it you cannot be sure if the session info was really updated in server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test this code :

firstpage.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = "john doe";
echo $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

secondpage.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

Comment: Ahmad Jan, It doesn't work because in the normal way, I assign value then try to get it. But it doesn't work then I suppose a debugging mode and write my debugging mode above.

Comment: Aha na I did not mentioned you have removed unset. meanwhile i tested it and find works fine in the way.

Comment: in wordpress it doesn't work